# Add lightning spinner until the elements are loaded on the UI

Tags: lightning-web-components

```
<template>
<template if:true={showModal}>

  <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Case" onsuccess={navigateToViewCase} onsubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
        <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true"
            aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open slds-modal_medium">

            <div class="slds-modal__container">

                <template if:true={loading}>
                    <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading"></lightning-spinner>
                </template>


                <header class="bckcol slds-modal__header">
                    <lightning-button-icon class="slds-modal__close" title="Close" icon-name="utility:close"
                        icon-class="slds-button_icon-inverse" onclick={handleDialogClose}>
                    </lightning-button-icon>

                    <h2 class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate header-string">
                        Case
                    </h2>
                </header>
                <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
                    <template for:each={caseSection} for:item="section">

                        <h1 key={section.name} class="slds-section-title--divider" data-aura-rendered-by="141:2;a">
                            <strong data-aura-rendered-by="142:2;a">{section.name}</strong>
                        </h1>



                        <lightning-layout key={section.name} multiple-rows="true">
                            <template for:each={section.fields} for:item="val">
                                <lightning-layout-item key={val.fieldApiNames} size={section.rowsize}>

                                        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                                            <lightning-input-field field-name={val.fieldApiNames}  data-type={val.fieldApiNames}
                                                required={val.required} disabled={val.readOnly}>
                                            </lightning-input-field>
                                        </div>

                                </lightning-layout-item>
                            </template>
                        </lightning-layout>

                    </template>


                    <template if:true={error}>
                        <c-error-panel errors={error}></c-error-panel>
                    </template>

                </div>


                <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                    <!--<lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small" label="Cancel" onclick={handleDialogClose}>
                    </lightning-button>-->

                    <!-- <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small" variant="brand" type="submit" label="Submit Case">-->
                        <button class=" slds-button_brand "   type="submit" >
                            Submit Case
                    </button>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>

    </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>
```

Above template takes sometime to complete rendering of all the elements. How can i  add lightning spinner until the UI is not yet completed rendering.

Comment: Looks like there's already a spinner. What's wrong with the behavior?

Comment: Can you also post the js controller for this LWC? It looks like you have a spinner that depends on the value passed to {loading}. Will be good to know the logic for setting this value.

Comment: I tried to set the spinner to true in the constructor.And set it to false in rendered callback.But then i saw rendered callback got called multiple times so I put a check in rendered callback that only if the wired method brought data to the js parameters then only make spinner false.The spinner does not show up itself even though set to true in constructor and made false in renderedCallBack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You can implement spinner in the below manner. Here I am using
>   recordEditFrom. Initially when the component loads the spinner is
>   visible. Once the onLoad method of recordEditForm gets called on the
>   load of the page indicating the data required to load recordEditform is
>   available I set the value of property to true and the spinner is no
>   longer visible. You can apply the same concept with wire services and
>   set the property controlling visibility of spinner to true when data
>   is available from wire service.

```
<template>
 <template if:false={areDetailsVisible}>
    <div class="slds-spinner_container">
        <div class="slds-spinner--brand  slds-spinner slds-spinner--small slds-is-relative" role="alert">
          <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading...</span>
          <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
          <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </template>
    <div>  
        <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name={objectApiName} onload={handleLoad}>
        <template if:true={areDetailsVisible}>
            <lightning-input-field field-name={lookupFieldApi} value={lookupValueDefault}
             onchange={handleChange}>
            </lightning-input-field>
        </template>
        </lightning-record-edit-form>
    </div>

</template>

import {
    LightningElement,
    api,
    track
} from 'lwc';


export default class LookUpFilterBasedOnRecordEditForms extends LightningElement {

    //object API name,lookupValueDefault and lookup field name send from calling component.
    @api lookupValueDefault = '';
    @api objectApiName = '';
    @api lookupFieldApi = '';
    @track areDetailsVisible=false;
    //on change event  to send selected value to calling component
    handleChange(event) {

        window.console.log("You selected value from lookUP LWC---->>>> " + event.detail.value[0]);
        let lookUpValues = {
            selectedValue: event.detail.value[0],
            lookupFieldApi: this.lookupFieldApi
        };
        const lookUpChangeEvent = new CustomEvent('lookUpChange', {
            detail: {
                lookUpValues
            },
        });
        // Fire the custom event
        this.dispatchEvent(lookUpChangeEvent);
    }

    // connectedCallback(){
    //     this.areDetailsVisible=false;
    // }

    handleLoad(event) {
       this.areDetailsVisible=true; 
        window.console.time("LDS call");
        //details coming on the load of form
        // The LDS will take a few seconds to load the component.
        const recUi = event.detail;
        window.console.timeEnd("LDS call");
        //  window.console.log("OnLoadData-", JSON.stringify(recUi));
    }
```